# Append MySQL field to the end of another field with some text as well

Tags: mysql

I have 50,000 records where I need to update a MySQL `description` column appending the value of a `custom_size` column and some text to the end of all the `description` columns.

**My MySQL Table**

```
UPDATE `d1_designs`
SET `description`= :description
```

`description` needs `custom_size` appended to it along with text

**OLD_DESCRIPTION_VALUE_HERE**`- Old custom_size Value =`**VALUE OF CUSTOM_SIZE HERE**

Can this be done with `concat()` and if so what format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the old value as if was a variable in the assignment:

```
UPDATE d1_designs
SET description = CONCAT("blah ", d1_designs.description, " MoRe StuFf");
```

You can also use any other field name on the right side of the SET:

```
UPDATE d1_designs
SET description = CONCAT_WS(" ", description, custom_size);
```